# Quartz2d and Instance Method

Tags: ios, class

I try to write my own custom class to do some 2d stuff. (TwoDOperations.h and TwoDOperations.m). Below are my files.

--------TwoDOperations.h------

```
@interface TwoDOperations : UIView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect withscene:(UIViewController *)sender;
- (void)drawRectV2:(CGRect)rect;
-(instancetype)init;
@end
```

--------TwoDOperations.m------

```
#import "TwoDOperations.h"

@implementation TwoDOperations

-(instancetype)init{
    self=[super init];
    if (self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect withscene:(UIViewController *)sender{
    UIView *myBox  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 10)];
    myBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [sender.view addSubview:myBox];
    }

- (void)drawRectV2:(CGRect)rect{
    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath
                            bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 200));


    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);
    [circle fill];
    [circle stroke];
   }

@end
```

As you see I have two methods to do some 2D things.

And my main methods is like this:

```
TwoDOperations  *twoD = [[TwoDOperations alloc]init];

CGRect  rect = CGRectMake(10,10,10,10);
[twoD drawRect:rect withscene:self];
[twoD drawRectV2:rect];
```

(I know rect is not used for now)

When I use  `<twoD drawRect:rect with scene:self>` it is successfully drawing. I can draw a rectangle. But when I use `<twoD drawRectV2:rect>` it is nothing. It doesn't draw anything? I check in debug mode and I find context is not null. I ask simply why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `drawRectV2:` method really does nothing. You're creating an image context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(200, 200)` and draw a circle to this graphic context, but you don't use result of this drawing. Creating of a graphic context just provides you with some graphic buffer (or in other words - graphic surface), and you draw into this buffer/surface. But you won't see result of drawing unless you draw to a system context provided by iOS views' drawing system (I mean a context obtained with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` when called in overridden `UIView`'s `drawRect:` method).

To fetch drawing result in your code, you need to call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` function which returns `UIImage`. Besides this, if you call the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` function then you must call the `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`. Please see the ["Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS", "Creating New Images Using Bitmap Graphics Contexts" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW8) for example of using the functions I mentioned above.

But there is another question. Let's suppose you obtain result of your drawing (i.e. `UIImage`) by calling `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`; what you're going to do with this drawing result, i.e. how would you use obtained `UIImage`?

And in general your implementation of the `TwoDOperations` class looks very strange. It seems you need to read more docs to understand concepts of iOS views' drawing. I'd recommend you to read the ["View Programming Guide for iOS", "Implementing Your Drawing Code" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW3).

As I understood your intent, you'd like to create a view doing some custom drawing, e.g. a circle. If this understanding is correct then I'd implement it in the following manner:

--------TwoDOperations.h------

```
@interface TwoDOperations : UIView

// No need to declare anything as we're only going to override UIView's methods

@end
```

--------TwoDOperations.m------

```
#import "TwoDOperations.h"

@implementation TwoDOperations

- (instancetype)init 
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);

    UIBezierPath *circle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    [circle fill];
    [circle stroke];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

@end
```

--------ViewController.m------

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    TwoDOperations* twoDOperationsView = [[TwoDOperations alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:twoDOperationsView];
}
```

In the example above, the `TwoDOperations`'s `drawRect:` method is called automatically by iOS drawing system, and UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() provides you with a correct system graphic context. The iOS drawing system then obtains result of drawing from that system graphic context and presents it onto display. You should never call `UIView`'s drawing methods by yourself, only system should do this. If, for example, you call the `TwoDOperations`'s `drawRect:` method manually in your code then most likely UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() won't return a correct graphic context, so drawing will not be done.

## UPDATE

According to your comment about progress bar, I'm updating my answer.

So, in general you'd like your custom view to draw different things depending on some external conditions. E.g. by default the view should draw one rectangle (progress bar background) and a smaller rectangle reflecting some default progress bar's value; if a user presses some button then progress bar value changes and a smaller rectangle should be redrawn with a new size. In this case, the best approach is to have different drawing in the your custom view's `drawRect:` method depending on data representing the progress bar value. You don't need to have 2 views to represent your progress bar; you need only one view added once in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. Then, when user presses some buttons you can change the custom view's data so that its `drawRect:` method will draw a new progress bar.

I'd implement this as follows:

--------TwoDOperations.h------

```
@interface TwoDOperations : UIView

// Progress bar's value, percents (from 0.0 to 1.0)
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat progressBarValue;

@end
```

--------TwoDOperations.m------

```
#import "TwoDOperations.h"

@implementation TwoDOperations

- (instancetype)init 
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.progressBarValue = 0.1f; // some default value
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);

    // Draw progress bar frame
    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 2.0f);

    CGFloat valueWidth = rect.size.width * self.progressBarValue;
    CGRect valueRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, valueWidth, rect.size.height);
    CGContextFillRect(context, valueRect);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

@end
```

--------ViewController.m------

```
#import "TwoDOperations.h"

// Declare your custom view as a property in your view controller's extension
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) TwoDOperations* progressBarView;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    self.progressBarView = [[TwoDOperations alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.progressBarView];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    self.progressBarView.progressBarValue = 0.6f;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I wonder if I want to draw something on  an event for example push something (button or something else). how can I do that? as my understanding I can use view method only in didLoad. Right?

Comment: Could you please describe in more details what you'd like to achieve? Some step-by-step scenario would be great.

Comment: I try to make custom progress bar. I have some buttons on screen . when user push a button my progress bar react to this event and its value change. For progress bar I plan to use two rectangle. One of them for frame and another one for progress value. Thank you and Best Regards

Comment: Please see the updated answer. Hope it clarifies things

Comment: That is wonderful. It is fully explain my questions. Thank you very much!